# Writing a Publisher and Subscriber to wirelessly communicate over 2 Linux PCs in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, nodes, ros

I have also published this question to Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Forums here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499530/writing-a-publisher-and-subscriber-to-wirelessly-communicate-over-2-linux-pcs-in and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494239&p=14174197#post14174197. I wanted to also post here to increase my chance of getting responses but please let me know if I should not repost here. I read that it is okay as long as I link the post but I am new to these platforms so sorry if I am mistaken.

I have code that is written in C that has a corresponding executable file and both work the same. Both run in a terminal and everything outputs into the same terminal. I am trying to make that code a publisher so that the output values can be sent to my other computer wirelessly which would need a subscriber program on that computer. I have successfully tested the basic ROS tutorials for using simple publishers and subscribers, but ROS only provides examples in Python and C++. I am not familiar enough with C to know how to translate those examples into C and I can't seem to find examples anywhere.

These examples are using strings, but I will be using integers and floats. I'm not asking anyone to translate the entire thing unless you really want to or already have. Any help or advice is appreciated. If there are any other websites, articles, or forums that I just haven't found please link them for me.

I am working with 2 Ubuntu 20.04 computers, one is ROSCube and the other is a Dell PC that has Linux running on it and both use ROS noetic. Thank you!!!

Here are the links for the examples I followed. (I tried to link them but the website wont let me post unless I format it like code).
`<http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29> <http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29> <http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines>`

I have tried all of these successfully I just don't know how to make them compatible to be integrated into my C file.

Comment: Note that the [tag:ros] tag states *"Please ask ROS related questions on https://robotics.stackexchange.com from now on."*.

Comment: Why are you trying to use C when the API is written in C++?

Comment: @Oka not sure why, but someone keeps editing the tag info. The robotics stack exchange is being used in place of answers.ros.org.